# Copying a file to an existing directory results in IOError [Error 21] is a directory

Tags: python

I get this error:

```
IOError [Error 21] is a directory
```

when I try to copy a file to an existing directory. I do it like this:

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

where `src` is a file and `dst` is an existing directory. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As I have said, `dst` is an existing directory. This is exactly what I want - to copy a file to a directory

Comment: yeah, the problem is that dst has to be the file path. try to do `shutil.copyfile(src, '%s/%s' % (dst, src.split()[-1]))

Comment: According to python doc: 'Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named dst'. If you want to copy to a directory, try `shutil.copy`

Comment: @bshuster. Please, make an answer from your comment. If it works, I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have already answered yourself in the question.

`dst` should be the path to the copied file. So if you want to copy the file to `/var/lib/my/` and your file is called `f1` then `dst` should be `/var/lib/my/f1.txt`

Try to use `shutil.copy` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765832/1929635) by [john-estess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4894194/john-estess)

```
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

or try to fix this using the following snippet

```
shutil.copyfile(src, '%s/%s' % (dst, src.split('/')[-1]))
```

Assuming src is the path of the file you want to copy, such as `/var/log/apache/access.log`, and `dst` is the path to the directory, where you want to copy the file, for example, `/var/lib/my` then the new destination is `/var/lib/my/access.log`.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will accept it in 8 minutes, when stackoverflow allows me to do it =)

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito \o/

Answer (score 11):

You're using the wrong function. You might want "copy":

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 1):

See code snippet to see how the source is the path to a file, AND the destination is also a path to a file (that doesn't yet exist until you run this function).

```
for file in orig_files:
    shutil.copyfile(SOURCE_PATH + file_name, DEST_PATH + file_name)
```